# require js paths not being recognised

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

**I am using RequireJS 2.0.2**

I have the following in a file used as the entry point.

```
require({

    "packages"  : ['bi/charts'],
    baseurl     : '/js/',
    paths       : {
        handlebars  : "lib/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6",
        jquery      : "lib/jquery-1.7.2.min",
        underscore  : "lib/underscore-1.3.3.min",
        modernizr   : "lib/modernizr-custom.2.5.3.min",
        BI          : "bi/BIf"
    }
});
```

however it only recognises 'jquery' and none of the other paths, it comes back with the following error:

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - [link]http://localhost:62033/js/handlebars.js"
handlebars.js
Script error http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
[Break On This Error]   

var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);
```

....thoughts?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to call config before requiring. Also pay attention to adding a slash to the path. Use:

```
"handlebars" : "/lib/handlebars"
```

Not

```
"handlebars" : "lib/handlebars"


  require.config({
    baseUrl: "/js/",
    paths: {
        "handlebars": "/lib/handlebars"
    },
  });
  require( ["handlebars"],
    function(handlebars, myModule) {
    }
  );
```

See also [Config Paths](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths)

Comment: figured it out. beacuse I am making multiple require calls in the page as it is being constructed the main.js file that contains the require.config call does not have a chance to load as the require() calls are executed first. had to place th require.config call within the page and not called from the main.js.

Comment: Then create an answer yourself and mark it solved so it looks answered. :)